# How to show images based upon which button is selected

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have created 4 buttons in my HTML file.
I have an object in my JavaScript file named products created using curly brackets {}.
Within this object, I have an Array named data created using square brackets [].
Within this Array, I have a number of different objects created using curly brackets {}.

Each of the objects within the Array are displayed correctly. I now want to create a filter, which will only show certain objects within the Array, depending on which button is pressed.

In my HTML file, I have this code:

```
<div id="buttons">
   <button id="all" class="button-value" onclick="filterProduct('all')">All</button>
   <button id="product1" class="button-value" onclick="filterProduct('product1')">Product 1</button>
   <button id="product2" class="button-value" onclick="filterProduct('product2')">Product 2</button>
   <button id="product3" class="button-value" onclick="filterProduct('product3')">product3</button>
</div>
```

In my CSS file, I have this code:

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

The object I have created in JavaScript:

```
let products = {
    data: [
        {
            productName: "Item 1",
            category: "product1",
            price: "30",
            image: "image-of-the-product-1.jpg",
        },
        {
            productName: "Item 2",
            category: "product2",
            price: "49",
            image: "image-of-the-product-2.jpg",
        },
        {
            productName: "Item 3",
            category: "product3",
            price: "99",
            image: "image-of-the-product-3.jpg",
        },
    ]
}
```

The filterProduct function in JavaScript:

```
// Parameter passed from button (Parameter same as category)
function filterProduct(value) {
    // Select all elements
    let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
    // Loop through the elements
    elements.forEach((element) => {
    // Display all cards on all button click
    if (value == "all") {
        element.classList.remove("hide");
    } else {
        // Check if element contains category class
        if (element.classList.contains(value)) {
            // Display elements based on category
            element.classList.remove("hide");
        } else {
            // Hide other elements
            element.classList.add("hide");
        }
    }
});
}
```

If the user clicks on the button with the product1 filter, only products with the category of product1 should show up. If the user clicks on a button with the product2 filter, only products with the category of product2 should show up. If the user clicks on the button with the product3 filter, only products with the category of product3 should show up. If the user clicks on the All button, all the products should be shown.

Comment: where is element with class card ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let products = {
  data: [{
      productName: "Item 1",
      category: "product1",
      price: "30",
      image: "https://via.placeholder.com/200x200",
    },
    {
      productName: "Item 2",
      category: "product2",
      price: "49",
      image: "https://via.placeholder.com/400x400",
    },
    {
      productName: "Item 3",
      category: "product3",
      price: "99",
      image: "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    },
    {
      productName: "Item 3",
      category: "all",
      price: "99",
      image: "https://via.placeholder.com/200x100",
    },
  ]
}

function filterAllProduct(value) {
  console.clear();
  let a = [];
  var container = document.getElementById("displayImage");
  let list = container.classList;
  list.add("uicomponent-panel-controls-container");
  for (var i = 0; i < products.data.length; i++) {
    container.innerHTML += '<img src=' + products.data[i]['image'] + ' />';
  }
}

function filterProduct(value) {
  console.clear();
  var newArray = products.data.filter(function(item) {
    return item.category == value;
  })[0];
  var html = [
    '<div class="uicomponent-panel-controls-container">',
    '<img src=' + newArray.image + '>',
    '</div>'
  ].join('\n');
  document.getElementById("displayImage").innerHTML = html;
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
  <button id="all" class="button-value" onclick="filterAllProduct('all')">All</button>
  <button id="product1" class="button-value" onclick="filterProduct('product1')">Product 1</button>
  <button id="product2" class="button-value" onclick="filterProduct('product2')">Product 2</button>
  <button id="product3" class="button-value" onclick="filterProduct('product3')">product3</button>
</div>

<div id="displayImage"></div>
```

```js
let products = {
  data: [{
      productName: "Item 1",
      category: "product1",
      price: "30",
      image: "https://via.placeholder.com/200x200",
    },
    {
      productName: "Item 2",
      category: "product2",
      price: "49",
      image: "https://via.placeholder.com/200x100",
    },
    {
      productName: "Item 3",
      category: "product3",
      price: "99",
      image: "https://via.placeholder.com/200x100",
    },
    {
      productName: "All",
      category: "all",
      price: "100",
      image: "https://via.placeholder.com/400x400",
    },
  ]
}
var getSelectedValue = '';
var html = '';

function filterProduct(value) {
  getSelectedValue = value;
  var image1 = '';
  switch (value) {
    case 'all':
      image1 = 'https://via.placeholder.com/200x100';
      html = [
        '<div class="uicomponent-panel-controls-container">',
        '<img src=' + products.data[0]['image'] + '> <span>' + products.data[0]['price'] + '</span>  \n',
        '<img src=' + products.data[1]['image'] + '> <span>' + products.data[1]['price'] + '</span> \n',
        '<img src=' + products.data[2]['image'] + '> <span>' + products.data[2]['price'] + '</span> \n',
        '</div>'
      ].join('\n');
      break;
    case 'product1':
      image1 = 'https://via.placeholder.com/200x200';
      html = [
        '<div class="uicomponent-panel-controls-container">',
        '<img src=' + image1 + '> ',
        '</div>'
      ].join('\n');
      break;
    case 'product2':
      image1 = 'https://via.placeholder.com/400x400';
      html = [
        '<div class="uicomponent-panel-controls-container">',
        '<img src=' + image1 + '>',
        '</div>'
      ].join('\n');
      break;
    case 'product3':
      image1 = 'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150';
      html = [
        '<div class="uicomponent-panel-controls-container">',
        '<img src=' + image1 + '>',
        '</div>'
      ].join('\n');
      break;
    default:
      // default code block
  }
  if (getSelectedValue == 'all') {

  }
  document.getElementById("displayImage").innerHTML = html;
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
  <button id="all" class="button-value" onclick="filterProduct('all')">All</button>
  <button id="product1" class="button-value" onclick="filterProduct('product1')">Product 1</button>
  <button id="product2" class="button-value" onclick="filterProduct('product2')">Product 2</button>
  <button id="product3" class="button-value" onclick="filterProduct('product3')">product3</button>
</div>

<div id="displayImage"></div>
```

If Data is static then you can use switch case this is how you can display image according button click

If Data is dynamic and you are not able to map that you can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to map that data

Comment: However, I want all the cards to show when the user click on the all button

Comment: didn't get your question.. please elaborate your question

Comment: If the user clicks on the 'All' button, all of the cards should be shown. If the user clicks on the button titled 'Product 1', only the cards in the product 1 category should be shown

Comment: @user20936799, Sorry, I have added solutions for both dynamic and static data.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find Working demo
[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-architecture-lbliqw?file=/index.html)

I have added my own card as of now but you can change this acording your necessity.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).